# Powershell: Measuring runtime with external Scripts by using [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]

Tags: powershell

I integrate several scripts into one main script `run.ps1`. I want to measure the total runtime of all scripts. However, this does not work with my method. I get values that are far too low.

To illustrate the problem, I have created the following script consisting of two files `my_external_script.ps1` and `run.ps1`:

**my_external_script.ps1**

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
```

**run.ps1**

```
# Initialize the Stopwatch
$StopWatch = [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()

# Execute my external Script
. "my_external_script.ps1"

# Stop the Watch
$Stopwatch.Stop()

# Print the Result
Write-Output "Total Runtime: $($StopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds) Seconds."
```

My expectation is that Stopwatch will return at least 60 seconds. However, I only get a few milliseconds.

[image]

**Do you have a solution for me as to how I can determine the total runtime of all scripts?**

Comment: What does your external script  contain? Are you sure it’s actually invoking anything, or does it just contain function definitions? Try replacing the contents of the external script with ```Start-Sleep -Seconds 60``` - does your stopwatch show the correct time for that?

Comment: My external Script calls Database Operations.

Comment: Fun Fact: when I wrap the Variable into a function, I get the correct result

Comment: "calls Database Operations" - using what tool or API? If you've dispatched an async routine or started a job or similar, the script might return before all the work is done

Comment: I have revised my question. The questions in the comments should therefore be superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Elapsed is a timespan type.  If you look at it, the seconds are converted to minutes, or you can use totalseconds.

```
$stopwatch.elapsed

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 1
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 13
Ticks             : 600138484
TotalDays         : 0.000694604726851852
TotalHours        : 0.0166705134444444
TotalMinutes      : 1.00023080666667
TotalSeconds      : 60.0138484
TotalMilliseconds : 60013.8484
```

You can also use the get-history command to see the start and end execution time (datetime types) of the previous command:

```
get-history -count 1 | fl

Id                 : 13
CommandLine        : .\run
ExecutionStatus    : Completed
StartExecutionTime : 12/10/2023 10:50:32 AM
EndExecutionTime   : 12/10/2023 10:51:32 AM
```